# ArrayList passes empty to the function

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am not even sure what to ask but I have been stuck in this for hours. I am trying to create an object (NodeReservation) within the class bookFlight that only contains a person or an ArrayList ("disguised as a Client"). However, this object (NodeReservation) is created with an empty ArrayList. Why could this be happening?

This is the important part of the class bookFlight:

```
void bookFlight(ArrayList<Persone> group) {
    NodeReservation newReservation = new NodeReservation(new Group(group));
```

}

the class Group is as follows:

```
public class Group extends Client{
    ArrayList<Persone> group;

public Group(ArrayList<Persone> group) {
    this.group = new ArrayList<Persone>();
}
```

}

Client is just an empty class so I can use it for a class Person (that also extends to Client) but with both types of objects ending in the same hashtable.

the class NodeReservation:

```
public class NodeReservation {
NodeReservation next;
Client client;

public NodeReservation(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
    next = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Because of `this.group = new ArrayList<Persone>();`. You don't use the `group` argument in the `Group` class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public Group(ArrayList<Persone> group) {
>     this.group = new ArrayList<Persone>();
> }
> ```

This code completely ignores the `group` parameter. If you want to copy it, you have to pass it to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
this.group = new ArrayList<>(group);
```

After that, the `group` *field* will be a distinct `ArrayList` object from the `group` *parameter*, but it contains the same elements in the same order. Adding or removing elements from one does not affect the other.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Dummy mistake on my part. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Group`'s constructor ignores the list passed to it and just creates an empty list. You should pass the argument to the `ArrayList` constructor instead of ignoring it:

```
public Group(ArrayList<Persone> group) {
    this.group = new ArrayList<Persone>(group);
    // Here ----------------------------^
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the solution so simple and still I didn't see it. Thank you for your time.